# Why does my SQL query fail?

Tags: mysql, random, limit

I'm using this to retrieve information from a database, the query always brings errors

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT '10'
```

It always brings up errors on either the `ORDER BY RAND()` or the `LIMIT '10'`.

Any reason why this is happening? Also is there any solutions to this?

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the 10

Answer (score 11):

Limit should be integer? 10 instead '10'.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM affiliate
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Note there are no quotes around 10

Answer (score 1):

The LIMIT parameter is a number, not a string:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Whitout the quotes.